# How to create new Pandas column with total daily minutes calculated from timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given the following `df` in which timestamps are not index:

```
   timestamp
0  2020-10-23 12:20:00-04:00  
1  2020-10-23 12:30:00-04:00  
2  2020-10-23 12:40:00-04:00
3  2020-10-23 12:50:00-04:00
```

I am trying to create a new column `minutes` that contains the total number of minutes as counted from 00:00:00.

So the above would output

```
   timestamp                      minutes
0  2020-10-23 12:20:00-04:00      740
1  2020-10-23 12:30:00-04:00      750
2  2020-10-23 12:40:00-04:00      760
3  2020-10-23 12:50:00-04:00      770
```

I've been trying [pd.timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) however I'm unable to set a begin time to reference from (in my case I'd want the minutes counted from `00:00:00 hs`). Importantly, `minutes` should be **integer** and not string.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt.normalize` to get the day, subtract, and divide the timdelta `1T`:

```
df['minutes'] = (df.timestamp - df.timestamp.dt.normalize()) // pd.Timedelta('1T')
```

Another option (obviously easy):

```
df['minutes'] = df.timestamp.dt.hour * 60 + df.timestamp.dt.minute
```

Output:

```
                  timestamp  minutes
0 2020-10-23 12:20:00-04:00      740
1 2020-10-23 12:30:00-04:00      750
2 2020-10-23 12:40:00-04:00      760
3 2020-10-23 12:50:00-04:00      770
```

Comment: @pepe Thanks! just update with another option, easier but specific for this use case :-).